# The initial value problem $y'=\sqrt {y}, \:\: y(0)=\alpha$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The initial value problem

$$\begin{cases}y'=\sqrt {y}\\y(0)=\alpha\end{cases}$$ has

$A.$ At least two solutions if $\alpha =0$

$B.$ No solution if $\alpha > 0$

$C.$ At least one solution if $\alpha > 0$

$D.$ A unique solution if $\alpha = 0$

**ATTEMPT**

I solved the differential equation as

$y(x) = \frac{x^2}{4} + \alpha +x\sqrt {\alpha}$

How do i choose correct options?

Comment: C is the answer right!!

Comment: I wonder if the solution could not better be $y(x) = \frac{x^2}{4}  \pm x\sqrt {\alpha}+ \alpha$

Comment: @Boris No, several options are correct.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici how ?

Answer (score 2):

Answer. A true, B false, C true, D false.

If $a=0$, uniqueness is violated.

Solution I. $\varphi(x)\equiv 0$.

Solution II. $\varphi(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}$

If $a\ne 0$, solution is unique (locally).

Answer (score -1):

The general solution is
$$
y^{-1/2}dy=dx\rightarrow 2\sqrt{y}=x+c
$$
Considering initial value we have 
$$
2\sqrt{y}=x+2\sqrt{\alpha}.
$$
Hence: i) If $\alpha>0$ the i.v.p has a unique solution in a neighborhood of $0$ (by existence-uniqueness theorem). ii) The i.v.p has not solution if $\alpha<0$. iii) If  $\alpha=0$ then it has at least two solutions: 1) $y=0$
, 2) $\sqrt{y}=x/2$. You can now verify which of the above options is correct or not.

Comment: This is indeed the general solution when $\alpha>0$ but you are missing tons of solutions when $\alpha=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "tons"?

Comment: Uncountably many.

Comment: I can not see more than two! (which means we have not unique solution when $\alpha=0$).

Comment: @Albert i have not understood anything

Comment: @Albert Which points to the fact that you did not refer with enough caution to the theorems about existence and/or uniqueness of solutions of differential equations, that you know... In the present case, try $y(x)=0$ for every $x\leqslant42$ and $y(x)=\frac14(x-42)^2$ for every $x>42$.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I revised my answer to "at least two solutions".

Comment: "The general solution" is still quite wrong when $\alpha=0$.